# Consuming Polymorphic Jsons with Retrofit and Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

My API sends me a polyphonic Json in with the variable `addon_item` can be either a String or an Array, I have spend days trying to make a CustomDezerializer for it without any success.

Here is the **Json response**:

```
({
    "code": 1,
    "msg": "OK",
    "details": {
        "merchant_id": "62",
        "item_id": "1665",
        "item_name": "Burrito",
        "item_description": "Delicioso Burrito en base de tortilla de 30 cm",
        "discount": "",
        "photo": "http:\/\/www.asiderapido.cloud\/upload\/1568249379-KDKQ5789.jpg",
        "item_cant": "-1",
        "cooking_ref": false,
        "cooking_ref_trans": "",
        "addon_item": [{
            "subcat_id": "144",
            "subcat_name": "EXTRA",
            "subcat_name_trans": "",
            "multi_option": "multiple",
            "multi_option_val": "",
            "two_flavor_position": "",
            "require_addons": "",
            "sub_item": [{
                "sub_item_id": "697",
                "sub_item_name": "Queso cheddar",
                "item_description": "Delicioso queso fundido",
                "price": "36331.20",
                "price_usd": null
            }]
        }]
    }
})
```

Here is the *Custom Dezerializer*, which includes BodyConverter that removes two braces that encompassed the Json response:

```
'''
/**
 * This class was created due to 2 issues with the current API responses:
 * 1. The API JSON results where encapsulated by parenthesis
 * 2. They had dynamic JSON variables, where the Details variable was coming as a String
 * or as an Object depending on the error message (werer whe user and password wereh correct.
 *
 */

class JsonConverter(private val gson: Gson) : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun responseBodyConverter(
        type: Type?, annotations: Array<Annotation>?,

        retrofit: Retrofit?
    ): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
        val adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type!!))
        return GsonResponseBodyConverter(gson, adapter)
    }

    override fun requestBodyConverter(
        type: Type?,
        parameterAnnotations: Array<Annotation>?,
        methodAnnotations: Array<Annotation>?,
        retrofit: Retrofit?
    ): Converter<*, RequestBody>? {
        val adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type!!))
        return GsonRequestBodyConverter(gson, adapter)
    }


    internal inner class GsonRequestBodyConverter<T>(
        private val gson: Gson,
        private val adapter: TypeAdapter<T>
    ) : Converter<T, RequestBody> {
        private val MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        private val UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8")

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun convert(value: T): RequestBody {
            val buffer = Buffer()
            val writer = OutputStreamWriter(buffer.outputStream(), UTF_8)
            val jsonWriter = gson.newJsonWriter(writer)
            adapter.write(jsonWriter, value)
            jsonWriter.close()
            return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, buffer.readByteString())
        }
    }


    // Here we remove the parenthesis from the JSON response

    internal inner class GsonResponseBodyConverter<T>(
        gson: Gson,
        private val adapter: TypeAdapter<T>
    ) : Converter<ResponseBody, T> {

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun convert(value: ResponseBody): T? {
            val dirty = value.string()
            val clean = dirty.replace("(", "")
                .replace(")", "")

            try {
                return adapter.fromJson(clean)
            } finally {
                value.close()
            }
        }
    }


    class DetalleDeProductoDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<DetallesDelItemWrapper2> {
        override fun deserialize(
            json: JsonElement,
            typeOfT: Type,
            context: JsonDeserializationContext
        ): DetallesDelItemWrapper2 {

             if ((json as JsonObject).get("addon_item") is JsonObject) {
            return Gson().fromJson<DetallesDelItemWrapper2>(json, ListaDetalleAddonItem::class.java)

            } else {

                 return Gson().fromJson<DetallesDelItemWrapper2>(json, DetallesDelItemWrapper2.CookingRefItemBoolean::class.java)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {

        private val LOG_TAG = JsonConverter::class.java!!.getSimpleName()

        fun create(detalleDeProductoDeserializer: DetalleDeProductoDeserializer): JsonConverter {
            Log.e("Perfill Adapter = ", "Test5 " +  "JsonConverter" )

            return create(Gson())
        }


        fun create(): JsonConverter {
            return create(Gson())
        }


        private fun create(gson: Gson?): JsonConverter {
            if (gson == null) throw NullPointerException("gson == null")
            return JsonConverter(gson)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **RetrofitClient.class**:

```
class RetrofitClient private constructor(name: String) {
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    fun getApi(): Api {
        return retrofit!!.create(Api::class.java)
    }

    init {

        if (name == "detalleDelItem") run {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JsonConverterJava.create(JsonConverterJava.DetallesDelItemDeserializer()))
//                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(percentDeserializer))
                .client(unsafeOkHttpClient.build())
                .build()
            Log.e("RetrofitClient ", "Instace: " + "detalle " +  name)
        }
    }

    companion object {

        //Remember this shit is https for the production server
        private val BASE_URL = "http://www.asiderapido.cloud/mobileapp/api/"

        private var mInstance: RetrofitClient? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(name: String): RetrofitClient {
                mInstance = RetrofitClient(name)
            return mInstance!!
        }
    }
}
```

Finally my **POJO**:

```
open class DetallesDelItemWrapper2 {
     @SerializedName("code")
     val code: Int? = null
     @Expose
     @SerializedName("details")
     var details: ItemDetails? = null
     @SerializedName("msg")
     val msg: String? = null


     class ItemDetails {
         @Expose
         @SerializedName("addon_item")
         val addonItem: Any? = null
         @SerializedName("category_info")
         val categoryInfo: CategoryInfo? = null
         @SerializedName("cooking_ref")
         val cookingRef: Any? = null
         @SerializedName("cooking_ref_trans")
         val cookingRefTrans: String? = null
     }

class ListaDetalleAddonItem: DetallesDelItemWrapper2(){
   @SerializedName("addon_item")
   val detalleAddonItem: List<DetalleAddonItem>? = null

}

class StringDetalleAddonItem: DetallesDelItemWrapper2(){
    @SerializedName("addon_item")
    val detalleAddonItem: String? = null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a shot at this and came up with 2 possible ideas. I don't think they're the only way to achieve this, but I think I can share my thoughts.

First, I've reduced the problem to actually only parsing the items. So I've removed retrofit from the equation and use the following jsons:

```
val json = """{
    "addon_item": [{
            "subcat_id": "144",
            "subcat_name": "EXTRA",
            "subcat_name_trans": "",
            "multi_option": "multiple",
            "multi_option_val": "",
            "two_flavor_position": "",
            "require_addons": "",
            "sub_item": [{
                "sub_item_id": "697",
                "sub_item_name": "Queso cheddar",
                "item_description": "Delicioso queso fundido",
                "price": "36331.20",
                "price_usd": null
            }]
        }]
}
""".trimIndent()
```

*(for when the `addon_item` is an array)*

```
val jsonString = """{
   "addon_item": "foo"
}
""".trimIndent()
```

*(for when the `addon_item` is a string)*

---

## First approach

My first approach was to model `addon_item` as a generic `JsonElement`:

```
data class ItemDetails(
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("addon_item")
  val addonItem: JsonElement? = null
)
```

*(I'm using data classes because I find them more helpful, but you don't have too)*

The idea here is to let `gson` deserialize it as a generic json element and you can then inspect it yourself. So if we add some convenience methods to the class:

```
data class ItemDetails(
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("addon_item")
  val addonItem: JsonElement? = null
) {
  fun isAddOnItemString() =
    addonItem?.isJsonPrimitive == true && addonItem.asJsonPrimitive.isString

  fun isAddOnItemArray() =
    addonItem?.isJsonArray == true

  fun addOnItemAsString() =
    addonItem?.asString

  fun addOnItemAsArray() =
    addonItem?.asJsonArray
}
```

So as you can see, we check the `addOnItem` for what it contains and according to that, we can obtain its contents. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
fun main() {
  val item = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ItemDetails::class.java)
  println(item.isAddOnItemArray())
  println(item.isAddOnItemString())
  println(item.addOnItemAsString())
}
```

I think the biggest advantage of this is that it's fairly simple and you don't require custom logic to deserialize. For me, the huge drawback is the type-safety loss.

You can get the add on as an array, but it will be an array of json elements that have to be "manually" deserialized. Hence, my 2nd approach tries to tackle this.

---

## Second approach

The idea here is to use Kotlin's sealed classes and have 2 types of add ons:

```
sealed class AddOnItems {
  data class StringAddOnItems(
    val addOn: String
  ) : AddOnItems()

  data class ArrayAddOnItems(
    val addOns: List<SubCategory> = emptyList()
  ) : AddOnItems()

  fun isArray() = this is ArrayAddOnItems

  fun isString() = this is StringAddOnItems
}
```

The `SubCategory` class is just what was inside the list. Here's a simple version of it:

```
data class SubCategory(
  @SerializedName("subcat_id")
  val id: String
)
```

As you can see the `AddOnItems` is a sealed class that has the only 2 possible types for your use case.

Now we need a custom deserializer:

```
class AddOnItemsDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<AddOnItems> {
  override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?) =
    when {
        json?.isJsonArray == true -> {
            AddOnItems.ArrayAddOnItems(context!!.deserialize(
                json.asJsonArray,
                TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, SubCategory::class.java).type))
        }

        json?.isJsonPrimitive == true && json.asJsonPrimitive.isString ->
            AddOnItems.StringAddOnItems(json.asJsonPrimitive.asString)

        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Cannot parse $json as addonItems")
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, this checks if add on is an array and creates the respective class and the same for string.

Here's how you can use it:

```
fun main() {
  val item = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(AddOnItems::class.java, AddOnItemsDeserializer())
    .create()
    .fromJson(jsonString, ItemDetails::class.java)
  println(item.addOnItems.isString())
  println(item.addOnItemsAsString().addOn)


  val item = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(AddOnItems::class.java, AddOnItemsDeserializer())
    .create()
    .fromJson(json, ItemDetails::class.java)
  println(item.addOnItems.isArray())
  println(item.addOnItemsAsArray().addOns[0])
}
```

I think the biggest advantage here is that you get to keep the types. However, you still need to check what it is before calling `addOnItemsAs*`.

Hope this helps